# RestEasy methods with no Path Parameters

Tags: jax-rs, resteasy

I have a class that looks like this:

```
@Path("/applications")
public class ApplicationActivity extends BaseGravityActivity {

 @GET
 @Path("/{application_name}")
 public Response getApplication(@PathParam("application_name") final String appName) {
    final Object app = doSth(appName);
    return ((app == null) ? Response.status(Response.Status.NOT_FOUND) : Response.ok(app)).build();
 }

 @PUT
 @Path("/")
 public Response editApplication(final Object v) {
    final Object updated = doUpd(v);
    return Response.ok(updated).build();
 }
}
```

Now, when I write my unit test case,

```
request = MockHttpRequest.put("/applications/");
request.accept(SupportedMediaTypes.TEXT_PLAIN.mediaType);
request.setInputStream(new ByteArrayInputStream(payload.toString().getBytes()));
response = new MockHttpResponse();
dispatcher.invoke(request, response);
```

I get javax.ws.rs.NotFoundException: Could not find resource for full path: applications/
the get method works fine. How should i correct this?

Note:
1. I think of my resource as a collection (a set to be precise) and the "put" method adds / replaces an item in the set. I don't think adding an argument (like app name) in the path makes sense for my resource.

2. If I add a @Path("/{app_name}") and pass app name, then the method works fine.

How do I get this to work without specifying the app_name in the put path.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `@Path` annotation and do a `PUT` to `/applications`.

You should also add the `@Consumes` and `@Produces` annotation to tell Resteasy which media types you support for the request and response.

```
 @PUT
 @Consumes(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
 @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
 public Response editApplication(final Object v) {
    final Object updated = doUpd(v);
    return Response.ok(updated).build();
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

I got it to work by removing the "/" in the @Path annotation associated with the class.

My code now looks like this

```
@Path("applications")
public class ApplicationActivity extends BaseGravityActivity {
  @GET
  @Path("/{application_name}")
  public Response getApplication(@PathParam("application_name") final String appName) {
     final Object app = doSth(appName);
     return ((app == null) ? Response.status(Response.Status.NOT_FOUND) : Response.ok(app)).build();
  }

  @PUT
  public Response editApplication(final Object v) {
     final Object updated = doUpd(v);
     return Response.ok(updated).build();
  }
}
```

And all is well now.

Of course - the @Produces and @Consumes are also now a part of my code.